# iOS 7 supportedInterfaceOrientation not working as intended

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-rotation

So I have root controller that can rotate to any orientations and a view controller that only shows landscape mode using supportedInterfaceOrientations

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

So when I present that view controller by setting the window's root controller to be that at some point of the app, like button press, it starts on landscape mode. Everytime it rotates it calls that method. But when I rotate to portrait it went portrait even though I told them to use landscape only. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that only the topmost view controller is consulted. For example, if you have a navigation controller and its root view controller, only what the navigation controller says is important. (And you can use the navigation controller delegate's `navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:` to give the answer you want.)

Comment: tried this and it works. However if I pop the controller, the status bar thinks that its still on landscape mode and if I push to a new view controller that supports all orientation & starts at portrait, it instead starts on landscape. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @PaoloPascua You can't. Push/pop does not change orientation in iOS 7.

Comment: but with this method its affecting subsequent view controllers.  For me, I sort of did the self.navigationController.delegate = self on appear and restore original delegate on dismiss

Comment: My point is, you can express your preference about what should happen if the user rotates the device, but you can't _force_ the _app_ to rotate contrary to the _current_ orientation of the device during push/pop. Only present/dismiss can do that.

Comment: sigh. Lets say I use this method to force my view controller to go landscape mode. K it worked. Now I want to go to a different view controller by push/pop. The next controller I expect to start at portrait ended up starting in landscape mode, which I don't want.